# Dimension of my Scaled ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, dimension

How can I determine the dimensions of my Scaled ImageView? I tried using getWidth() & getHeight it always returns 0. My xml layout for the ImageView is as follows:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/my_image" />
```

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably calling getWidth() method too early. The width and height of your ImageView will not be available until the View has been rendered on the screen. Try getting them within onWindowFocusChanged:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    int width = iv.getWidth();
    int height = iv.getHeight();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This solution is easy. But there is an issue. When the device orientation is changed from landscape to portrait it throws exception.

Comment: You will have to check your logcat to see the exception cause.

Comment: I checked my LogCat. It says NullPointerException at line 103 of my MyActivity.java file. 

But line 103: is just int leftMargin = imgView.getWidth() + 10;

How it is possible to not to have a mull pointer exception when in Landscape while in Portrait?

Comment: Because your activity is being recreated. Your ImageView is null, and before you get its width, you'll have to get it from your layout. Where are you instantiating the ImageView?

Comment: The Image src is specified at at XML. I am just using: ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
 to get the ImageView.

Comment: Make sure that when you rotate the device, onCreate() is being called, and thus your image retrieved correctly from the layout.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14249/discussion-between-debopam-and-chinaski)

Answer (score 0):

You won't get those dimensions in onCreate. The view isn't measured yet and the hierarchy is not set. Those will work but you need to use them somewhere after the app has drawn the screen or the alternative is to set a ViewTreeObserver to notify you when the layout is set.[ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html)

Here is how its done:

1. call `getVieeTreeObserver()` to get a reference to the viewTreeObserver in  your activity.

then add a onGlobalLayoutListener:

```
 observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout()
            {   
                ViewTreeObserver obs = MyActivity.this.getViewTreeObserver();
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
```

Inside this `onGlobalLayout` method you can use your view and get its width and height and do whatever with them.

Comment: MyActivity.this.getViewTreeObserver() - doesn't exists.